# Sum sequence using Stolz–Cesàro

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, summation

I have this sequence, and I need to find the convergence of the sum sequence.
The answer is - sum equal π/4.
But I tried to solve it by Stolz–Cesàro, as you can see in the picture, And what I got is lim is 0, and I don't understand why.
I would glad if someone could help me with this, in understanding what I did wrong and how to solve it correctly.

Thanks

$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \frac{n}{n^2 + k^2}$

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n}{n^2+1^2}+\frac{n}{n^2+2^2}+\dots + \frac{n}{n^2+n^2}= \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{n}{n^2+k^2}$$

By Stolz–Cesàro stolz
$$= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n+1}n -\sum\limits _{k=1}^n n}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n+1}n^2+k^2 -\sum\limits_{k=1}^n n^2+k^2 }$$
[image: exc]

Comment: [Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34121/42969). Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. – For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Stolz–Cesàro requires starting from a **quotient**. You **don't** have a quotient.

Answer (score 2):

> **Stolz-Cesàro theorem case $\frac{*}{\infty}$:-**
> If $b_n $ is a monotone increasing sequence and $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} b_n = \infty $,
> and if $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{b_{n+1}- b_n}= l \in \overline{\mathbb{R}} $, then  $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n }{b_n}=l$.

Notice that your limit is $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty }\sum\limits _{k=1}^n \frac{n}{n^2+k^2} $ and not $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty } \frac{\sum\limits _{k=1}^n n}{ \sum\limits _{k=1}^n n^2+k^2} $ so you can't use Stolz-Cesàro theorem  theorem like that. In other words you mixed what is the numerator and the denominator of you limit and then distributed the sum over the quotient which of course is not correct.

$$L :=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty }\sum\limits _{k=1}^n \frac{n}{n^2+k^2}  = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty } \frac{1}{n} \sum\limits _{k=1}^n \frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^2}= \int_{0}^1 \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx =\frac{\pi}{4}$$